# How can I cause a python script to run everytime I open a Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

I just started using the Google API and I was able to code some cool stuff (cool to me) on Python, but I want to find a way to have the program run without me having to open up Spyder.

I have a spreadsheet with all my cryptocurrency balances. I wrote a code that would scan a price-tracking website and enter the USD value for each balance in a separate column. I want the script to run (update the prices) every time I open the sheet. Is this possible?

I could not find any information even discussing this, and the little information I found was related to Excel. Can I do this on Google Sheets?

Comment: No.  There are no macros in Google Sheets.  You can certainly have a Python app that runs every few hours and uses the Google APIs to update the Google Sheets document, but in that case why aren't you just using a database?

Comment: "but in that case why aren't you just using a database?" I assume this is because OP wants to have an easy way to view the data.

Comment: I don't undrstand why you want to use python. A script in GAS is enough.

Comment: You can't run a Python script automatically after opening a Sheet (albeit you could run it each X minutes and let it update the Sheet), but you can run an App Script. Would that be a valid approach in your scenario?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script in the past that downloads the values ​​when you open the spreadsheet. But you can also trigger the function to run at a frequency.

```
function onOpen(){
  relaodJson()
}

function relaodJson(){   
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var der = f.getLastRow()+1
  var col = columnToLetter(f.getLastColumn())
  f.getRange('A'+der).setValue(new Date())
  var sourceRange = f.getRange("B3:"+col+"3");
  var targetRange = f.getRange("B"+der+":"+col+der);
  targetRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues());
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true})
  f.getRange('A1').setValue(!f.getRange('A1').getValue());      
}

function pricePair(currencyPair) {    
  var url = 'https://api3.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=' + currencyPair;
  var reponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = reponse.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  return data.price;  
}

function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18l4EJ4FmKfvUeEt56kYZcoQVRRYiA6Kbm6U4xoHC-CQ/copy